# Change color of paper text on a photo. (Bitmap)

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I'm developing an Android application. I have photos of a white paper which has some text written on it.
Background is always whitish color.(Color of paper). Text color is always dark grayish. I have these photos on a bitmap format.

What I want to do is changing colors of these bitmaps so text color will become pure black and background will become pure white.

I have some sample code but it's slow and it's not working well if there is a soft-medium shadow on a paper.

What is the fastest and reliable way to do this? I don't want to paint soft-medium shadows to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer opencv functions that best fit your need, but I think you should implement it on your backend and use it with restful APIs.
[Thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) will do the job perfectly.You should just set the parameters right.

> OpenCV supports a wide variety of programming languages such as C++, Python, Java, etc., and is available on different platforms including Windows, Linux, OS X, Android, and iOS.

You can find your way with its [documentation on android](https://opencv.org/android/).